# Post Ckeditor data to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor

My Ckeditor post variable returns as having the input I need. When I insert it into the column everything inserts, BUT the ckeditor data.
This is my function to insert:

```
    public function SubmitReply() {
        $query = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO {$this->tprefix}posts(guid,poster,content,postdate)
        VALUES(:guid,:poster,:content,:postdate)
SQL;
        $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':guid' => $_POST['guid'],
            ':poster'   => $_POST['poster'],
            ':content'  => htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor1']),
            ':postdate' => $_POST['postdate'],
            ));
            return $resource->rowCount();
    }
```

And my form has:

```
<form id="reply" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="DEF_FORUM_SUBMIT_REPLY">
   <input type="hidden" name="guid" id="guid" value="<?php DEF_TOPIC_NAME($_GET['topic']); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="poster" id="poster" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key']['userid']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="postdate" id="postdate" value="<?php echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">


   <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</form>
<p style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Post Reply" id="submit_reply">
</p>
```

It seems that the post for `editor1` actually isn't passing now. I have no clue as to why at this point.